# How to solve javax.el.MethodNotFoundException

Tags: java, jpa, jsf

I'm trying to develop a simple CRUD operation with JSF and JPA. I've already developed the create operation and the read operation. Now I'm trying to implement the delete operation, but when I'm trying to delete I have this error

```
 javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @54,25 action="#{book.removeBook(book)}": Method not found: it.crud.data.Book@3bc35357.removeBook(it.crud.data.Book)
javax.faces.FacesException: #{book.removeBook(book)}: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @54,25 action="#{book.removeBook(book)}": Method not found: it.crud.data.Book@3bc35357.removeBook(it.crud.data.Book)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:110)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book {

    private Integer id_book;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String category;
    private String year;
    private String price;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_book")
    public Integer getId_book() {
        return id_book;
    }
    public void setId_book(Integer id_book) {
        this.id_book = id_book;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="author")
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Column(name="category")
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Column(name="year")
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Column(name="price")
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


}
```

Bean class:

```
@Stateless
public class BookBean implements BookLocal, BookRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="CRUDPersistence")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void createBook(Book book) {
        this.entityManager.persist(book);
    }

    public List<Book> readContatti(){
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b").getResultList();
    }

    public void deleteBook(Book book) {
        this.entityManager.remove(book);
    }
}
```

Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="book")
@RequestScoped
public class BookManagedBean implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Book b;

    @EJB
    private BookLocal bookBusiness;

    public BookManagedBean() {
        b = new Book();
    }

    public Book getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Book b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void storeBook() {
        bookBusiness.createBook(b);
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks(){

        return bookBusiness.readContatti();
    }

    public String removeBook(Book b) {
        bookBusiness.deleteBook(b);
        return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

index.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<h:head>
    <title>Book</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Book</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="12" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputText value="Name " />
            <ui:inputText value="#{book.b.name}" />
            <h:outputText value="Author " />
            <ui:inputText value="#{book.b.author}" />
            <h:outputText value="Category " />
            <ui:inputText value="#{book.b.category}" />
            <h:outputText value="Year " />
            <ui:inputText value="#{book.b.year}" />
            <h:outputText value="Price " />
            <ui:inputText value="#{book.b.price}" />
            <ui:commandButton value="Add" icon="fa fa-fw fa-plus"
                action="#{book.storeBook()}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="form">
        <ui:dataTable value="#{book.books}" var="book"
            style="margin: 2em;" rowKey="#{book.id}">
            <ui:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.name}" />
            </ui:column>
            <ui:column headerText="Year">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.year}" />
            </ui:column>
            <ui:column headerText="Author">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.author}" />
            </ui:column>
            <ui:column headerText="Category">
                <h:outputText value="#{book.category}" />
            </ui:column>
            <ui:column headerText="Price">
                <h:outputText value="$#{book.price}" />
            </ui:column>
            <ui:column style="width:100px;text-align: center">

                <ui:commandButton action="#{book.removeBook(book)}"
                    icon="fa fa-trash"></ui:commandButton>
            </ui:column>
        </ui:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Where is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hi .. did you read the error message? The answer is right there .. *"Method not found: it.crud.data.Book@3bc35357.removeBook(it.crud.data.Book)"*. Your source code also proves that this method does indeed not exist. You have programmed this method in `BookManagedBean` class not in `Book` class. Please tell which part exactly of the error message you didn't understand.

Comment: @BalusC The method removeBook is in the BookManagedBean class. In this method I call ’’’bookBusiness.deleteBook(b)’’’.  In the index.xhtml I wrote removeBook in the same way I wrote the storeBook method. The storeBook method works, while the removeBook method gives the error, so where is the problem? I hope you understand. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data table var name conflicts with your bean name, both `book`. Rename either one. For example:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bookBean")
```

```
<ui:commandButton action="#{bookBean.removeBook(book)}" ../>
```